# Dygraphs synchronization error

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Due to some issues related to slow chart drawing when using `synchronizer.js`, I updated to the `latest version`. Using this new version vastly improved the speed with which the web page loaded and the charts synced up. I also like the addition of the range option.

However, I am now getting **errors** with the selection option set to the default "true".  The error console throws an `Uncaught TypeError` saying `'getRowForX'` is not a function.

The zooming is synced and the range option are working as expected.

Any thoughts as what could be causing this? I don't see the `getRowForX` method defined anywhere else in the `synchronizer.js` code.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the line 201 in syncronizer.js by

```js
var idx = gs[i].findClosestRow(gs[i].toDomXCoord(x));
```

Comment: You just saved the day. This should be included in docs as a temporary fix until next released version.

Answer (score 3):

`getRowForX` is a new function [defined in `dygraph.js`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/bf50de0db3094fc5155efc8aee14112df2545e42/src/dygraph.js#L3698) at `HEAD`, rather than in a released version. You'll need to build dygraphs from github if you'd like to use the latest version of `synchronizer.js`.

Or you can wait for the next official release of dygraphs, but no guarantees about when that will happen!

Comment: I see a bunch of dyragph Javascript files on github, I assume many or all of them make up the `dygraph-combined.js` file. Are all of them required to make the code function properly, or could I just add in the `getRowForX` function to the current `dygraph-combined.js` file I have for the time being?

Comment: Check out the "Development" section in `README.md`.

Comment: OK, thanks. Very new to all of this so not exactly sure what I'm doing, but will give it a shot.